# Is it possible for Power BI to consume a Azure AD Authenticated Web API as a data source using organisational authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to develop an AAD Authenticated NET API that PowerBI can consume to retrieve analytical data from our Azure deployed custom web application. I am trying to use the Organisational Account Auth in Power BI, but it always returns an error: "We were unable to connect because this credential type isn't supported for this resource."

I've looked through many online sources (Microsoft and third party), including the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/. I have experimented with a range of coded configurations and are returning the WWW-Authenticate header back with the 401. Unfortunately, I am no closer to establishing an authenticated connection. Does anyone know if there are some coded sample resource or tutorials along with a detailed explanation of the required Azure config, including any App registration, Service App and other configurations, so we can determine what I am are currently doing wrong.
learn.microsoft.comlearn.microsoft.com
Power Query documentation - Power Query
Power Query is used to filter, combine, and mash up data from one or more supported data sources. (96 kB)